# Open CV generic Mat function headers

Tags: c++, templates, opencv

In OpenCV it's common to access a pixel in a `Mat` object like so:

```
float b = A.at<float>(4,5);
```

The problem is, if you don't know the type of data apriori, you're stuck. Is there a way of writing generic function headers that accept a `Mat` with template type `T`? I'd like to build functions for linear algebra calculations, and I don't want to have an `if` clause separating `double` and `float`. Something like:

```
 void func(Mat <T> a) { 
     a.at<T>(3,4) = ...
```

Is this possible in OpenCV?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible simply by templating your function :

```
template<typename T>
void func(Mat a) { 
    a.at<T>(3,4) = ...
```

But note that you have no easy way to constraint the type T to be only double or float, and your algorithm won't probably work on other types, but it may not be an actual problem.

Also note the drawbacks of using templates : [What are the disadvantages of using templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734990/what-are-the-disadvantages-of-using-templates)

Comment: This code doesn't compile - have you tried this or were you just guessing?

Comment: I wasn't guessing but I have to admit that I didn't try to compile it sorry, there were a typo inside the function.

Comment: Well actually I didn't pay much attention to the Mat class of openCV, i thought it was the Mat class that was templated as your code suggests but it's actually only the method, so the typo is the other way around. The last edit should compiles toward the openCV Mat class.

Answer (score 3):

It appears one more way to do this would be to use the `Mat_` object instead of `Mat`:

```
template<typename T>
void func(Mat_ <T> a) {
   cout << a(0,0) << endl;
}
```

If you want to pass a `Mat` to `func`, you must specify the type:

```
Mat a;
func(Mat_<float>(a));
```

If you use a differnt type than the original `Mat` type, OpenCV will preform the conversion for you.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV 2 Cookbook](http://www.laganiere.name/opencvCookbook/) page 40 claims that it's impossible. Also, regarding Mat_:

" Using the at method of the cv::Mat class can sometimes be cumbersome
 because the returned type must be specified as a template argument for
 each call. In cases where the matrix type is known, it is possible to
 use the cv::Mat_ class which is a template subclass of cv::Mat.

```
cv::Mat_<uchar> im2= image; // im2 refers to image 
im2(50,100)= 0; //access to row 50 and column 100
```

Since the type of the cv::Mat_
 elements is declared when the variable is created, the operator()
 method knows at compile-time which type to return."

**EDIT**: Use Mat.type()

```
Mat image=imread("image.bmp");
cout<<image.type();
```

Console output:

```
16
```

Wiki: The method returns the matrix element type, an id, compatible with the CvMat type system, like CV_16SC3 or 16-bit signed 3-channel array etc.