# How do I create a 1-D mat in OpenCV and initialize all the entries to zero?

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix, initialization, opencv-mat

The following piece of code does not seem to work. There is a similar question here [How to fill Matrix with zeros in OpenCV?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17041758/how-to-fill-matrix-with-zeros-in-opencv) but, I want a 1-D mat, not a 2-D mat as mentioned in this link.

```
int histSize = 8;
Mat colorHist;

for (int i = 0; i < (histSize * histSize * histSize); i++)
    colorHist.at<float>(i) = 0.0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like that:

1 - First you create a float array which is your 1-D data structure:

```
float arr[10] = {0}; // initialize it to all 0`s
```

2 - Now create your opencv matrix as follows and fill the array into it:

```
cv::Mat colorHist = cv::Mat(2, 4, CV_32F, arr);
```

3 - if you want to access individual entries use something like:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    colorHist.at<float>(0,i);
}
```

where `i` is the index of the entry you want `from 0 to 9`.

or just:

```
colorHist.at<float>(0,2);
```

if you need individually. here we get the entry with index `2` which will return `0` of course since the matrix is all zeros at that point.

EDIT: As Nicholas suggested:

```
cv::Mat colorHist = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 10, CV_32F); // size=10
```

is a shorter way of creating a 1-D row matrix with all zeros if you do not want to deal with a float array (credits go to Nicholas). and access is of course:

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    colorHist.at<float>(i);
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Can you please explain it part by part? Also, how do I access the elements? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In the code you have posted, you have not initialized the Mat to any size or type. However, there is a very easy way to initialize a matrix with zeros.

### Initialising Matrix values to 0:

```
cv::Mat colorHist = cv::Mat::zeros(1, histSize, CV_32F);
```

This will produce a row vector (1-dimensional) with `histSize` columns, `CV_32F` simply refers to the data type the matrix is dealing with (`float` in this case).

If you wish to work with column vectors instead, simply swap the dimensions:

```
cv::Mat colorHist = cv::Mat::zeros(histSize, 1, CV_32F);
```

### Accessing elements:

```
for(int i = 0; i < histSize; i++)
    float c = colorHist.at<float>(i);
```

Comment: Nicholas, that`s very elegant solution. Thanks!